# Build local iphone project without source control using jenkins

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build-automation, jenkins

I want to build an local iPhone project without source control using jenkins. However I havent had any luck with the documentation or searching the web. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without source control?

Comment: I need to take the automated build and run some UITestAutomation scripts on it. Need to automate the whole process. Getting the build from jenkins and then running tests on that build.

Comment: Well you can use absolute paths with the build tools, so you can point to your local project but I would strongly recommend using source control, even if you wouldn't use jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using source control BUT:

1. Create a new job, enter a meaningful name and select "Build a free-style software project"
2. Select "None" from the "Source Code Management" section
3. Select "Add A Build Step" -> "Execute Shell" and add the following

   ```
   cd /your/project/dir
   xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -project your_project.xcodeproj -target your_target clean
   xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -project your_project.xcodeproj -target your_target build
   ```
4. You can then also change the "Build Periodically" setting in the jenkins job to have it run every hour or whatever
5. Save the job

If you're expecting the xcodebuild tool to codesign your work and jenkins is running locally then it'll probably pop up a keychain window at some point during the "build" process.